# Error when using the "use" in php

Tags: php, composer-php

In my code, the server returns error when using the term "use". For example the following code:

```
use Spire\Settings;
use Spire\Resources;
use Spire\Utils;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

use Silex\Application;
```

The server returns me the following error:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING or '(' in /home/inoshare/public_html/api/app.php on line 8
```

What is wrong with the server configuration?

Comment: I think you have some error in your code. If it is misplaced symbol or something like that. The error you receive is at line No. 8, but not in the beginning which make me think you have PHP 5.3 or greater at the application. You should give more details (more code) about that file metioned in the error (app.php).
@PHPWeblineindia, please consider specifying the problem by commenting first before adding an aswer to precise the area of the problem.

Comment: @Rolice,use Namespace\to\class is only available if version > 5.3.That's why I have put notes for the same.Check touchmx answer,he had exact problem.

Comment: @touchmx,If my answer helps to resolve your issue you can accept my answer.Thanks in advance.

Comment: @PHPWeblineindia, yes I know that, but it could be a variety of reasons especially when the line is No. 8 and you have some code above. I do not say its incorrect, but precising the problem first is preferred, before publishing an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@touchmx,Please check my below notes.

**Notes :**

(1) Make sure It's running **PHP 5.3 or later.**

(2) If they are running an earlier version they won't have support for namespaces.

Please check **`phpinfo()`** for PHP version.

Answer (score 1):

I checked my php version and I see **5.2.7**.
The use of syntax "use Namespace\to\class" is only available starting with version **>= 5.3** of PHP.

Looks like problem solved

Comment: please use comments below the answers given to your question. You have currently made a conclusion of your situation in an answer which incorrect.